# How to create specific style button in javaFx using css

Tags: css, javafx

I want to create button in JavaFX having the following style:

[image: Button Image]

I tried to use linear-gradient, but not able to add horizontal and vertical gradient at the same time.

Will you please help to create CSS for the above button style?

As per the comments I am including the css, that I have done so far :

```
.button-sales {
    -fx-border-width: 4px;
    -fx-border-color: white rgb(7,2,226) rgb(7,2,226) white;
    -fx-background-radius: 0,0,0,0;
    -fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,254);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;

    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, rgb(7,2,226) 0%, rgb(7,2,226) 100%),
        white,
        rgb(0,0,254);
}
```

but above css not exactly match with the button I required. Please help.

Comment: Please share your code with us that you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadUsman, .button-sales {
    -fx-border-width: 4px;
 -fx-border-color: white rgb(7,2,226) rgb(7,2,226) white;
    -fx-background-radius: 0,0,0,0;
    -fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,254);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, rgb(7,2,226) 0%, rgb(7,2,226) 100%),
        white,
        rgb(0,0,254);
}

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the additional information. Code in comments like that is unreadable.